# In single page apps, is it standard to do sorting and filtering on the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I was developing a new app with ReactJS and was implementing sorting/filtering on the client side. However, after browsing larger open source SPAs, I see many doing it server side via the API. Are they any cons to doing it client side besides performance?

Comment: You might want to ask this on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If the sorting is culturally dependent, there may be a huge benefit to doing it at the client.

Answer (score 4):

This depends mostly on the total potential size of the data.

#### Client side

If this is something where you'll never have more than, e.g. 50 items, and not much data is needed for the list view, then you can just send it all to the client.

An example of this would be a sublist which has limited size imposed.  For example, if your site is a store, and you can only have 50 items for sale, then you can just send them over at once.  The downside here being that if you later change that to a higher number, you need to rewrite it with server side pagination/sorting.

#### Server side

Often in an application, you could have thousands or millions of items in a list.  An example of this would be [questions/unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered), where each item takes a considerable amount of data to represent, and at the time of writing is over 2 million items.

Trying to load 2 million stackoverflow questions onto the client at once is infeasible, and is much more expensive for your server and database even at 1000 items.

By default, **sort/filter should be done on the database because it's often required to allow scale**, even for a single user.  In specific cases you could load everything onto the client as an optimization.

#### Client Side Database

This is particularly useful when network is your bottleneck, and users will use this application for extended periods of time, possibly while offline.

When the application starts, you download a large amount of data, and store that in IndexedDB (or simple objects, depending on the quantity).  You can then interact with this data without being restricted by server side apis, or network performance and reliability.

You will probably never need this, but I think it's worth mentioning.  I have heard of this being deployed in web software for receptionists, and other office work where a long startup time doesn't matter (and only the first startup would be very long).  Facebook Ads employ this in their 'power editor', which essentially downloads all of the configuration, and you then reupload everything when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. If you are doing paged results and not retrieving the entire set, then you would need to go back to the server to get an updated list if the user clicks to sort the data.

For example you fetch a list of fruits & vegetables. Since the result size is limited to 3 it renders the below table.

```
Name
--------------------
Apple

Banana

Carrot
--------------------
1 | 2 | 3 | Next >
```

If the user sorts by name, you will need to go back to the server to get an updated list since the client does not know of the other fruits & vegetables. The server would then return something like:

```
Name
--------------------
Zucchini

Yams

Xigua
--------------------
1 | 2 | 3 | Next >
```

Apart from that, I cant really think of another reason to sort on the server side (excluding performance from what you have mentioned)

Hope that makes sense